# Method to handle bad file descriptor error

Tags: c, sockets, recv

**Scenario:**
Connection is established between client and server.The client side connections are closed and client is destroyed. At the server side some of the connections closed are detected but some are not.So there are socket descriptor which are like dangling pointers.Select on these returns Bad file descriptor error but it is not possible to find the invalid fd .

**Question:**
In the above scenario, where the client connection does not exist how should I handle these `BAD FILE DESCRIPTORs` .Can I call `recv()` on these ?

Answer (score 1):

The signature for [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) is:

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *restrict readfds,
           fd_set *restrict writefds, fd_set *restrict errorfds,
           struct timeval *restrict timeout);
```

Doesn't the `errorfds` set give you a list of descriptors which generated an error condition, such as `EBADF`?

You can call `recv()` or any other function that takes a file descriptor with the bad file descriptor; you will likely get back an `EBADF` error from the function called (unless it detects a different error condition before detecting `EBADF`).

Comment: recv() returns 0 in this case as if the connection with client is closed but select returns bad file descriptor for the same socket descriptor.

Comment: You may need to distinguish between what the system thinks of as a 'bad file descriptor' and what you think of as a bad file descriptor.  The system thinks that a file descriptor that has been closed (or never opened) is bad.  The mere fact that there's no sender at the far end of a read descriptor is not an error; the file descriptor is likely reported as 'ready', and when you read from it you get the EOF indication (which is zero bytes read).  The file descriptor isn't bad; it just won't ever return any data.  When the `recv()` call returns zero, you conclude that the client has gone away.

Comment: I close the connection at client side,at the same time at server side if i do select the fd gets set and i do recv() which returns 0 and i conclude that the client is closed.But in some scenario select will return Bad file descriptor error.Do you know in which scenario select returns EBADF on a descriptor?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you messed up different situations.

If a connection is closed at client side, and you call select() on the server side socket, FD_READ will be triggered and recv() will return zero, then you can close the socket at server side.

If a connection is lost and the server does not receive the FIN signal, you need to have heartbeats between client&server as well as a timer on each server side socket to detect the TCP half open situation.

The "bad file descriptor" error only happens when you call API on an already closed socket.

Comment: so you mean in a TCP half open situation select will return a EBADF?

Comment: No. For TCP half open socket, select() will return nothing, no read event, nor write event. Usually a heartbeat timer is used to detect TCP half open socket and then close it.

Comment: Why  for a socket descriptor which had become bad select returns bad file descriptor and recv returns 0?

Comment: I think this is the case: 1) recv() returns 0 means peer closed the socket; 2) the socket is closed; 3) select() return "Bad Descriptor". I don't believe that recv() could return 0 on an already closed socket.

Comment: If i use fcntl(F_GETFD..) to find which socket fd had gone bad fcntl returns 1 and select returns EBADF.In which scenario is it possible?